# How to insert multiple records using JSON in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy, python-3.6

I want to insert multiple records using `json` like this:

```
posts = [{
            "title": "First Post",
            "user_id": 1
        }, 
        {
            "title": "Second Post", 
            "user_id": 2
        }]
```

How do you save `posts` like this way?:

```
post = Post(title=posts.title, user_id=posts.user_id)
db.session.add(post)
db.session.commit()
```

I am using flask 1.0.2 and Python 3.6.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
for post_dict in posts:
    db.session.add(Post(**post_dict))
db.session.commit()
```

The `**` magic is explained ([Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)).